# Compiz key bindings do not work in Virtualbox VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, compiz

I'm running Ubuntu in a virtualbox VM on windows, and none of the key-bindings that I define for compiz plugins (such as Grid and Put) work. I've tried letters and numbers by themselves, as well as combined with ALT, CTRL, and Super, but all fail.

Any help, insight, tips, pointers, and general (constructive) abuse is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem for the grid plugin by enabling 3d acceleration on the virtual machine under the display settings.